# Calculate the percentage of word using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actual case is to read the total count difference in percentage basis. Since `hello` comes in first word its count-'1' but in the 3rd rows Hello count -2. Now I need to calculate the percentage of the word usage like previously it is 1, now it is 2 percentage is 50% increased. So I have to calculate percentage for particular word from previous and current.

```
+----+--------------------+--------+-------------+
| No |        Text        |  Word  |  Totalcount |
+----+--------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 |  Hello Welcome     | Hello  |           1 |
|  2 |  Hello Text        |  Text  |           1 |
|  3 |  Hello Text! Hello |  Hello |           2 |
+----+--------------------+--------+-------------+
```

I have formed the following SQL query to calculate the percentage but it leads error.

```
select Totalcount * 100/SUM(TotalCount) from table where Word = 'Hello'
```

It leads following issue:

> Word is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Expected Output is to add the percentage of the count in the newer column.

Percentage calculation formula here i have used is `TotalCount/ SUM(TOtalCOunt) * 100 where the word = "Something".`

Result of the above query should be like below.

```
(No column name)
33%
67%
```

Please suggest me the way the SQL querying to do this.

Comment: Please, post the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your expected output

Comment: Added the expected output.

Comment: Can you explain the row no. 1 and 2 ... how is 1 => 50% and 2=> 100%???

Comment: (TotalCount)*100/(SUM(TotalCount)) where word = 'something'

Comment: which sql server version you are using

Comment: SQL version is 2016

Comment: Why the `Percentage` for the first row (`No = '1'`) is `50`? Thanks.

Comment: zhorov i have edited the expected output. please look into it. Percentage will be came based on the word we given in the query

Comment: @Zhorov, Since 33% comes using this percentage calculation formula. 1/3*100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, next approach using windowed `SUM()` may help:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    [No] int, 
    [Text] varchar(100), 
    Word varchar(100), 
    TotalCount int
)
INSERT INTO #Table
    ([No], [Text], Word, TotalCount)
VALUES
    (1, 'Hello Welcome',     'Hello', 1),
    (2, 'Hello Text',        'Text',  1),
    (3, 'Hello Text! Hello', 'Hello', 2)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    [No], [Text], Word,
    CONVERT(numeric(5, 0), (TotalCount * 1.0 / Total * 100)) AS Percentage
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(Totalcount) OVER (PARTITION BY Word ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Total
    FROM #Table
) t
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------
No  Text                Word    Percentage
------------------------------------------
1   Hello Welcome       Hello   33
3   Hello Text! Hello   Hello   67
2   Hello Text          Text    100
```

Answer (score 1):

You could determine number of words by counting spaces and then calculating the percentage:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'Hello world! Hello';
declare @word varchar(100) = 'Hello';

select sentence, word, TotalCount * 1./(len(sentence) - len(replace(sentence, ' ', '')) + 1) Percentage
from (
    select @str sentence, @word word, 2 TotalCount
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

you need window function

```
select count(word)/SUM(TotalCount) over(partition by word order by word)
from table where Word = 'Hello'
```

Comment: Checked your query also leads the same issue.

Comment: same issue obtained